# angular material mat-table is throwing a 'template undefined' error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a table designed with angular material. All the required markup is present in this table yet each time i run the app it throws

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'template' of undefined

I've checked and double checked it if all the MatHeaderCellDefs are there, i checked whether the datasource was somehow undefined after ngOnInit, which isn't the case. I checked whether i made a typo somewhere, not the case either. I know this should be super simple but i've been literally trying to resolve this error for the past one and a half hour now and still no luck. Could someone please look at my code and see if i've missed something? Again, its not the datasource thats null. Everything gets retrieved correctly during the GET request.

Heres the HTML.

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource] ="produceNameList" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="produceName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCelDef>Produce name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let produce">{{produce.produceName}}</td>
      <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> Average </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="produceCount">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Cost </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let produce"> {{produce.produceCount}} </td>
      <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> {{getAverage()}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  </table>
```

Heres the ts

```
  produceNameList: MatTableDataSource<ProduceMap> = null;

  displayedColumns = ['produceName', 'produceCount'];

  produceMapArray: ProduceMap[] = new Array<ProduceMap>();
  ngOnInit() {
    this.moderatorService.getProduceCountList().subscribe(result => { 
        (<any>Object).entries(result).forEach(entry => {
          this.produceMapArray.push(new ProduceMap(entry[0], entry[1]));  
        });
        this.produceNameList = new MatTableDataSource<ProduceMap>(this.produceMapArray);
    });
  }


  getTotal(): number{
    return this.produceMapArray.map(produceMap => produceMap.produceCount).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
  }

  getAverage(): number{
    return this.getTotal() / this.produceMapArray.length;    
  }
```

Thank you

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to add the object class

```
export class ProduceMap {
  constructor(public produceName: string, public produceCount: number){}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong spelling : matHeaderCelDef

**Replace** this

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCelDef>Produce name</th>
```

with

```
 <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Produce name</th>
```

Comment: the format is not the problem, i use the same format that is used in the example table at the angular material website https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview. The problem still persists after trying your format.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap-editable.js are you using? @Maurice

Comment: thx @Debojyoti, it was a type error after all… But the debugger message was very misleading! It did not point at the typo, rather it pointed to the first line of the markup. It wasn't a syntax error either :( So i kept thinking it had something to do with the datasource..

Comment: It's not the debugger problem.
Debugger doesn't have all the valid reasons for each error in it's dictionary.
So whenever it encounter an error with no pre defined reason, it just point to the immediate effect of that error :) @Maurice